# Company License? google sdk

Tags: vb.net, google-drive-api

I am an amateur programmer. I started programming a long time ago just for fun. Now i am using my knowledge for professional purposes. I am developing and application that provide a user-friendly interface to create plannings and reports for my Company.

The thing is, i am new on this, and don't know much about licensing. If i want to develop any application, futhermore if i want to integrate my app with Google SDK(i want to use Google Drive as a online storage), do i need to require(and pay) for any license? 
Only our employees will use this app and will not be selled or something like this. Just to make a job easier. And since this the first that i am using my programming knowledge for professional purposes, i have no idea what to do.

Thanks for your reply...

Comment: No there is no licence fee. The SDK is on a permissive licence (probably Apache, but I haven't checked). This isn't really the type of question that SO is designed for.

Comment: what have you researched so far?